# Is it correct to write "mehr Informationen" or "mehrere Informationen"?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence is it correct to write **mehr** or **mehrere**?

> Kürzlich haben Sie sich auf unserer Website angemeldet, um mehr
>   Informationen über **__** zu erhalten.

Comment: Often, quantifying the amount of information (i.e. *mehr*, *weitere*) can be substituted by writing "..., um sich über ___ zu informieren."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Mehrere Informationen" does not mean what you want it to mean. "Mehrere" means several.

"Mehr Informationen" is fine, "mehr Information" would also fit.

Comment: Quite right, "mehr" und "mehrere" have a different meaning. I want more... "Ich will mehr", I want several of... "Ich will mehrere..."

Comment: "Mehr Information" is rather used in a scientific context (IT/mathematics/cybernetics).

Answer (score 9):

Another widely used alternative in the meaning of your example is:

> ... weitere Informationen ...

Comment: You beat me to it, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd translate it back to English:

> mehr Informationen  –  more information
>
> mehrere Informationen  –  several pieces of information

From this it's clear that you want *mehr Informationen*.